# The coast of a river

Tags: recreational-mathematics

On the coast of a river, there are four docks : A, B, C, D (in that order). It takes a ferry two hours to get from point B to point A, one hour from point B to point D and three hours from point C to point A. In what direction does the river flow - from A to D or from D to A? Explain the solution.

Comment: What have you tried?  You are looking for a segment where you know it is faster in one direction than the other. You can subtract the times for overlapping segments to determine the times for some other segments.

Answer (score 3):

With obvious notation:

$$1) \qquad(C\to B)=(C\to A)-(B\to A)=3-2=1$$

$$2)\qquad \left((B\to D)=1 \quad \mbox{and} \quad D\ne C\right) \Rightarrow (B\to C)<1$$

so: $(C\to B)>(B\to C)$ and the river flows as $A\to B\to C\to D$.